# How to answer a question begins with "has"?

Tags: tense

[image]

> Q: Has your daughter come back from Australia?
>
> A: Yes. She ____ there for three years.
>
> A. has stayed
>
> B. stays
>
> C. stayed
>
> D. had stayed

I think the answer is D because "staying there" happened in past before "coming back" (past of the past).

But the "standard" given answer is C. Why?

Comment: Both C and D are correct. D would normally be followed by something else that happened. In this case, however, what followed was her coming back—so, it's understood in context. However, I think C is the more common of the two; and that more people would naturally pick C than D. But if the test is indicating that D is *wrong*, then it's a poor test. (And if it's asking which is more common, that's somewhat subjective—and it's still a poor test.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks a lot!